# Is there a name for this method of sorting?

Tags: sorting, mergesort

It appears to be possible to sort an unordered linked lists of equal size by splitting the list with a middle pointer, then recursively comparing the front two elements of each list and moving the minimum node to a new list.

For example, with an LL of integers 1 5 8 3 6 2 4 7, you can split the elements into two groups: 1 5 8 3, and 6 2 4 7. From there, you create a new list by comparing the head of each list to get 1 5 3 8 2 6 4 7. Split again into 1 5 3 8 and 2 6 4 7, then sort to get 1 2 5 6 3 4 7 8. One more split and sort gives you 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8. This also works if you reverse the order of the inputs, but I've not yet tried a different starting order.

I'm guessing this method of sorting has been discovered before, does anybody know its name?